# Why are the colors different in vi at the console vs in a Windows telnet session

Tags: colors, telnet

I noticed that when I use vi at the console, the code highlighting looks good and is nice and easy to read.  When I edit the same file via a telnet session, the colors are all low-intensity and it's impossible to read.  Anyone know what is causing that?

Thanks!

update: *Windows* telnet - sorry I didn't specify that earlier - subject updated accordingly

Comment: If you do `echo $TERM` in each of those 2 sessions, does it output the same terminal type?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  So when I'm at the console, it's "linux" and through telnet it's "ansi".  When I do it through PuTTY it's "xterm", but even through PuTTY it's illegible.  Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: I also just noticed that it's not just limited to VI, it's also the case when doing directory listings.  Seems like it's not rendering the colors high-intensity like in the console.

Comment: So upon doing more research, it looks like the default Windows telnet (sorry, didn't specify that it was Windows telnet) does not support 256 colors :(

Comment: I guess that means this question is solved?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.  I'm not sure how I mark it as solved?